# Response from gcm server

Tags: android, asp.net, google-cloud-messaging

When i'm trying to send a message to gmc server i get response like this : 
`id=0:1369151570496475%5193e1bc66d6cf16`

and notification is not being recieved.
What does response mean? 
Sorry for my english ;]

```
public string SendNotification(string deviceId, string message)
{
        string GoogleAppID = "xxxxx";
        var SENDER_ID = "xxx";
        var value = message;
        WebRequest tRequest;
        tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

        string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + deviceId;
        Console.WriteLine(postData);
        Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();


        tReader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();

        return sResponseFromServer;
    }
```